# Can a gpio-leds device have a supply?

Tags: device-tree, imx6

I have a board with GPIO driven LEDs. These LEDs can only be activated if the power supply is on. To do this, I have to set on a GPIO "led_enable".

I think I will have to use a regulator but I don't know how to declare the LED device as a consumer of this regulator.

Is something like that do-able ?

```
/ {
    reg_led_enable: regulator-ledenable {
        ...
    };

    gpio-leds {
        compatible = "gpio-leds";

        ???-supply = <&reg_led_enable>;

        led1 {
            gpios = <...>;
            ...
        };
    };
};
```